# FedEx COD Implementation

Tags: magento-1.9, api, fedex

My Client want to implement FedEx Cash On Delivery Service. We are already using FedEx Shipping API.Any one have any information about Fedex COD in magento or even in php please share with me. Any Help is appreciable.

Comment: You need to check API documentation and customize API request for COD
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php

Comment: Do you use magento Cash on delivery option right now?

Comment: is the code contain in app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php?

Comment: No I don't want to use magento COD option at all

Comment: yes @AnupChaudhary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this my own below are some details-->

Check if you have 'ShipWebServiceClient.php' file present in magento folder if not then you must need to integrate Fedex API client service. This file basically related to fedex APIs.

In this file find `$masterRequest['RequestedShipment'] = array()` and see addSpecialServices function is there or not.

master array should look like as below-->

```
$masterRequest['RequestedShipment'] = array(
        'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
        'DropoffType' => 'REGULAR_PICKUP', // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, DROP_BOX, BUSINESS_SERVICE_CENTER and STATION
        'ServiceType' => 'PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT', // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...s
        'PackagingType' => 'YOUR_PACKAGING', // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
        'TotalWeight' => array('Value' => 9.0, 'Units' => 'LB'), // valid values LB and KG
        'Shipper' => addShipper(),
        'Recipient' => addRecipient(),
        'ShippingChargesPayment' => addShippingChargesPayment(),
        'SpecialServicesRequested' => addSpecialServices(),
        'LabelSpecification' => addLabelSpecification(), 
        'RateRequestTypes' => array('ACCOUNT'), // valid values ACCOUNT and LISTs
        'PackageCount' => 3,              
        'RequestedPackageLineItems' => array(
            '0' => addPackageLineItem1()
        )
    );
```

and addSpecialServices() will look like as below

```
function addSpecialServices(){
    $specialServices = array(
        'SpecialServiceTypes' => array('COD'),
        'CodDetail' => array(
            'CodCollectionAmount' => array(
                'Currency' => 'USD', 
                'Amount' => 150
            ),
            'CollectionType' => 'ANY' // ANY, GUARANTEED_FUNDS
        )
    );
    return $specialServices; 
}
```

You can find SpecialServiceTypes = COD in the given function,

Now your job is simple pass COD to this file fedex will automatically generate COD in shipping label.

Also, call fedex to enable COD service for your account.

Comment: What is the file path for ShipWebServiceClient.php?

Comment: This looks like you just overwrote Priority_Overnight then added 150 as a flat amount to charge for it?

Comment: No,  The amount and currency will take by Fedex it self, I don't know but that 150 is given already in fedex API docs